# Random HTTP 500 error for certain directories

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

I got a `Debian 8.11` vServer with `Apache2`.
With the server I received a gratis domain.
I bought an extra domain and set it's A records to the vServer IPv4 address.
For the extra domain I have a valid SSL certificate that I installed.

Accessing certain directories / files on my webserver from my browser show different results depending on the domain I'm using.

> https://mydomain.test/phpmyadmin/  -   HTTP Error 500  (nothing in the
> logs btw) http://thefreedomain.test/phpmyadmin/ - Showing me the index
> page
>
> http://1.1.1.1/phpmyadmin/   - Showing me the index page, too

Now **other directories** work on all 3 domains for some reason.

And the weirdest part is:
Without having changed anything, a 500 error that occured at a certain path with a index.php using my new domain randomly disappeared after awhile.

Been trying to find the cause of this for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention it so I assume you don't have any weird VirtualHost configuration or something, so I would look take a look at errors in PHP logs and MySQL logs too, edit php.ini if necessary - you may have a script that extracts information from the hostname or header.  The behaviour with domains seeming to fix themselves is probably from an initial error being cached.

Comment: Couldn't find any hints in all those logs

Comment: @user3367856 do you have PHP error logs setup (can you supply the relevant lines from phpinfo();?) and what logs do you have coming from MySQL?